# Прыгает фиксированное меню при наведении на другие блоки

Tags: html, css

Суть проблемы в том, что если навести на какой-то элемент на странице, к которому прописано `transform:`, то фиксированное меню прыгает на 1px вниз потом, через 0.5 сек, становится обратно на 1px вверх.

При этом, ни один элемент не меняет свои свойства ширины\высоты\отступов.

Залил код: [jsfiddle menu](https://jsfiddle.net/dL2e5x27/)

Т.к. пишу на Sass, скопировал компилированный css.
Как воспроизвести ошибку? Она не всегда появляется, чтобы меню начало прыгать, надо промотать до самого верха, чтобы фиксированное пропало, потом крутить вниз и наводить на блоки. Если с первого раза все отлично - надо еще раз так сделать, обычно через раз срабатывает. Данный код лучше скачать и открыть в хроме. Jsfiddle не воспроизводит ошибку(хотелось бы знать почему). Ставил префиксы - результат тот же. В firefox работает правильно

Так же видео записал: [dropbox video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtkl2y5jtulg26l/12.3gp?dl=0) внимание на красную полосу сверху

Очень давно с этой проблемой сталкиваюсь, много у кого спрашивал, ответ так и не получил...

Comment: Че-то ничего не понятно на этом видео, может снимете его не мобильником, а каким-нибудь screen-capture-ом? Ну и в моем Хроме никаких лишних движений при наведении на этот блок нет.

Comment: вот захват экрана
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ievqrlee969y3o1/test.mp4?dl=0